# post-receive hook on Windows - GIT_WORK_DIR: no such file or directory

Tags: git

I try to setup my post-receive hook on git (windows).
Here is the script:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "post-receive hook"
GIT_WORK_TREE=/d/test git checkout -f
```

When I do git push on my local repository I see this echo message, script is called properly.

But the checkout doesn't run! There is an error in console view:

```
remote: fatal: Could not switch to '/d': No such file or directory
```

But when I put this command in Git Bash, it works!

Comment: Are you using cygwin instead of the bash included with msysgit? Because with cygwin, the path would be `/cygdrive/d/test`.

Comment: No, I have installed Git with Git Bash only - without adding git to PATH. Maybe I should try to add git to PATH?

Comment: I don't think the `PATH` is the issue (you can `echo` the `$PATH` to check). Maybe try also to set `GIT_DIR`. Display also the `pwd`, and a `ls /d`.

Comment: It is something suspicious here. Looks like I get my local disks, not from the remote machine!

`remote: /cygdrive/d/test
remote: ls: /d: No such file or directory
remote: /Volumes/D/Git/myrepo.git
remote: fatal: Could not switch to '/cygdrive/d': No such file or directory`

Comment: this is the result from following post-receive script:

`#!/bin/sh
export GIT_WORK_TREE=/cygdrive/d/test
echo $GIT_WORK_TREE
ls /d
pwd
git checkout -f`

Comment: Did you try `GIT_WORK_TREE=/Volumes/D/test git checkout -f` then?

Comment: It works! But this is bad news for me. What if I will push from another computer? I have other clone on my windows machine where this path is not available :/

Comment: I have added an answer for addressing your point.

Comment: VonC - thank you. Now I know that I should have a common path names between Mac and Windows

Answer (score 2):

From the comments:

```
GIT_WORK_TREE=/Volumes/D/test git checkout -f
```

works.

However, the [OP RobertM](https://stackoverflow.com/users/727858/robertm) comments:

> What if I will push from another computer? I have other clone on my windows machine where this path is not available

That is a different issue, and can be solve for instance with a drive naming convention: one can decide to associate whatever path the remote repo is (`d:\test` or any other path) to a specific drive letter (`X:` for instance), with the [Windows `subst` command](http://ss64.com/nt/subst.html).

Answer (score 0):

I have mysysgit running on a webserver that I push to from my local workstation and I use the following post-receive script:

```
#!/bin/sh
git --work-tree=/cygdrive/d/www --git-dir=/cygdrive/d/CodeRepositories/tempRepo.git checkout -f
```

What stumped me at the beginning was the file not being in a UNIX format, you can use Notepad++ to change it.  Note, I'm using cygwin to do the push over SSH so your directory names may need to be modified.