# How do I execute a post-receive hook on msysgit on Windows hosted by Apache?

Tags: msysgit

I'm setting up a Git server on a Windows host.  I have installed the latest Apache, and have it working with msysGit.  I'm not using SSH at all; I can push and pull through HTTP.

Now I want to add a post-receive hook to notify my build server, but I can't figure out how to do that.  I see the sample hook scripts in the repository on the server, but I'm confused about what to do there.  Do I put a Windows batch file there, named `post-receive.bat`, or do something else?

I'm a bit fuzzy on details of what this is all doing, but Apache is executing c:\Program Files\git\libexec\git-core\git-http-backend.exe when it sees a Git URL.  Is git-http-backend.exe going to trigger the post-receive hook?

**Update**
I'm getting closer.  Here's my hook, in `hooks/post-receive` in my repo:

```
#!/c/Program Files/Git/bin/sh
curl http://mybuildserver:8080/job/Whazzup/build
```

I changed the shebang from `#!/bin/sh` because on Windows I don't have that.  Now in the Apache error log I get the message `error: cannot spawn hooks/post-receive: No such file or directory`

Incidentally, Git bash's `chmod` does not seem to work.  But I was able to get the permission on `post-receive` to `rwxr-xr-x` by renaming the sample file.

**Update**
I changed the shebang line back to `#!/bin/sh`, but I still get the same error in the Apache error log: `error: cannot spawn hooks/post-receive: No such file or directory`.  As a test I opened a Git bash prompt in the hooks folder, and executed the hook with `./post-receive`, and it worked.

**Update**
Now I'm wondering if I have a different problem.  Taking VonC's advice, I tried running Apache httpd from the command line under my own account, instead of as a service under LocalSystem.  Still the same thing.  Pushing and pulling work fine, but the hook doesn't execute.  Then I tried getting Apache out of the equation.  From a Git bash prompt on the same computer as the repo, I did a clone (via filesystem), modify, commit, and push.  But the hook still didn't execute.

**Update**
OK, I had a silly problem in my hook script, but now at least it executes when I push to the repo from the same computer (via filesystem).  But not when I push through Apache.  Apache is now running under a regular account, and the Apache account has full control of the repository.  The push works fine, but the post-receive hook doesn't execute.

Comment: You should keep the shebang to `#!/bin/sh`: it will work. This is executed in an msysgit bash session.

Comment: Thanks. See my update in the question.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5697210/msysgit-error-with-hooks-git-error-cannot-spawn-git-hooks-post-commit-no-su should help you there.

Comment: I have edited my answer to include possible resolutions for your error message

Comment: Strange. It could be related to the executable bit (not supported on Windows, as in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9414942/git-post-receive-hook-not-working-on-remote-windows-server

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Apache is executing `c:\Program Files\git\libexec\git-core\git-http-backend.exe` when it sees a Git URL. Is `git-http-backend.exe` going to trigger the post-receive hook?

No, it will pass the command (`clone`, `push`, `pull`) to `git` itself.
The [`post-receive` hook](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks#Server-Side-Hooks) will be executed after the push has been completed, and it is a *bash* (unix shell) script, as illustrated in " [post-receive hook on Windows - GIT_WORK_DIR: no such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8193729/post-receive-hook-on-windows-git-work-dir-no-such-file-or-directory) ".

See also " [git windows post pull](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6286982/git-windows-post-pull) " to see where you can create that `post-receive` script (in the `.git/hooks` of your repo): it has nothing to do with your http Apache service in front of the repos.

---

Regarding the error message "cannot spawn hooks/post-receive: No such file or directory", you can refer to " [msysgit error with hooks: "git error: cannot spawn .git/hooks/post-commit: No such file or directory"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5697210/msysgit-error-with-hooks-git-error-cannot-spawn-git-hooks-post-commit-no-su) ":

- The shebang must be `#!/bin/sh`
- Apache must run as a regular user instead of Local System, in order to benefit from the environment variables defined for said regular user.
- `<path_to_git>\bin` must be in the `PATH`

Comment: I can run Apache as Local System fine as long as <path_to_git>\bin is in the PATH.

Comment: @KennethXu yes, but it won't work, since local system doesn't have the same environment variable that your regular account has.

Comment: @VonC, Local System does have access to environment variables, you just need a restart: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/821761

Comment: @dazweeja I agree  Local System does have access to environment variables, but surely it cannot access *user* environment variable? At least not the same user than Kenneth? And some important variable can be defined there.

Comment: @VonC: I came back to this after a few months.  Your third point was my problem.  My Git is in <path_to_git>\cmd, and that was on my path, so I thought that was adequate.  Following your instructions EXACTLY got it working.

Comment: >>At least not the same user than Kenneth? And some important variable can be defined there.
@VonC, late response but what are other important variables and why it has to be user variable? cannot you just add it to system environment? My Apache/Git running as Local System for years now, all I did was to add it to system path.

Comment: @KennethXu any other git-related variable that a user might want to define. For instance `GIT_SSH`, in order to use `openssh` or `plink.exe`. Plus, I like the idea to be able to access/modify those variables without needed elevated privileges. But if you don't have any extra variable, then by default Local System should work just fine.